# Allowing users to create an email address

Tags: php, email

I am creating a website and would like to allow users to create their own email forward.

Basically, the site will allow groups to create pages on the site, each of which will be able to have its own domain name.

I would like users to be able to automatically create an email address on the site that will forward any incoming emails to their own email account.

Right now I have to manually set these up in my hosting account control panel but I'm hoping there is a way to do this automatically.

Does anyone have experience with doing something similar?

Comment: Do you have any sort of control or access to the mailer except through the admin panel?

Comment: well what email system are you using? are you using cpanel? do you have whm? what OS is your server running?

Comment: As Jason asked, we will need a LOT more information.  Different Mail servers have different levels of support for this type of thing.  With the specifics we might be able to help

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of my abilities because I don't really have any experience with email systems.  Right now this is a very early-stage project and is being hosted on Fatcow.  I don't have any access to the mailer outside of the admin panel as far as I know.  That said, I'm really not looking for a description of how to do it, but mainly just want to know if it's possible for future reference.

Comment: Try asking this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @rwain - why would you move this to serverfault? What part of it is about servers?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this service offered by Microsoft.  It just might be what you are looking for. http://explore.live.com/windows-live-admin-center

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe any emails delivered to your catchall to a PHP programming (or whatever server side program you use) and then have it parse the email for the email address sent to, look it up in the database, pull out the real address of the user, and then email the contents of the email to them.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this really takes me back. I honestly haven't used this service in probably close to 10 years, but [Everyone.net](http://everyone.net/) provides an MX hosting service that allows users to sign up for their own address. You just provide a link to `http://{yoursite}.mail.everyone.net` from your site, and visitors will be able to sign up for a free email account on your domain.

Now, since it's been such a long time, I'm not sure if this account type is still free or not, but I do remember the service was quite good. This was a time before Gmail, but their webmail interface was relatively good as well. (From [what I've read](http://controlcenter.everyone.net/main/html/email_started.html), it sounds like free accounts probably won't have IMAP or POP access.)

If Everyone.net isn't to your liking, you might try other MX hosting services. Searching Google just now, I came across another one called ZapZone or something like that, but it looks super spammy, and I can't imagine their webmail interface being very good. But [some of these](http://www.emailaddresses.com/email_ownservice.htm) might be alright. Or if you use Google Apps, there may be something in the Google Apps Marketplace too.